# Cannot read file with Windows minifilter driver

Tags: c, windows, driver

I have a minifilter driver based on the example Minivers. See https://github.com/guidoreina/minivers.

I am getting error codes on some files on the FltCreateFile which is to read the input file.

The error codes that I am receiving are

> -1073741757 0xC0000034
>
> STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Followed by another attempt

> -1073741757 0xC0000043
>
> STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION

I am unsure where to go or change in order to troubleshoot the issue. I have looked at the MSDN page for FltCreateFile.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltcreatefile

Unfortunately the return values documented do not match the errors I am receiving.

Running on Windows 10 1803.

I have tried modifying the Share access flags but still end up with the same errors.

I have done some more testing/investigation and decided to monitor a single directory in my case C:\temp within the minifilter. I believe my problem lies in the PreOperationCallback, as to when it calls the copy file. Below is my PreOperationCallback

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PreOperationCallback(_Inout_ 
PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, 
_Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext)
{
  //PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION renameInfo;

  /* IRP-based I/O operation? */
  if (FLT_IS_IRP_OPERATION(Data)) {
  /* Open file? */
    if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE) {
    /* Open file for writing/appending? */
     if (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.SecurityContext->DesiredAccess &
      (FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_APPEND_DATA)) {
    return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, DEFERRED_IO, FALSE);
  }
} else if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION) {
        
  switch (Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass) {
    
    case FileDispositionInformation:
          if (((FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION*) Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer)->DeleteFile) {
            return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, FALSE);
          }
                      
      break;
    case FileEndOfFileInformation:
    case FileRenameInformation:
      
     //   //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564824/how-to-cancel-a-rename-operation-in-minifilter-driver
        //renameInfo = Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer;
        //DbgPrint("Rename info length- '%u'", renameInfo->FileNameLength);
        //memcpy(buf, renameInfo->FileName, renameInfo->FileNameLength);
        //DbgPrint("Rename info - '%wZ'", renameInfo->FileName);
        

      return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, TRUE);
      }
    }
  }

return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}
```

I get the errors listed above when I right-click in the temp directory and create new rich text document or if I copy a file to the directory. A new file is created in the c:\temp and I receive the errors in the debugger. NB: I have tried different files with different casing to confirm that I had no issues with filename casing.

Now if I delete the file I get the correct results, which is being done via:

```
case FileDispositionInformation:
  if (((FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION*) Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer)->DeleteFile) {
            return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, FALSE);
  }
                      
 break;
```

The process_irp - checks the file and generates a new location on where to move it to, it then calls the copy_file if all the criteria has been met.

```
BOOLEAN copy_file(PFLT_FILTER filter,
              PFLT_INSTANCE instance,
              UNICODE_STRING* dest,
              UNICODE_STRING* src)
{
    HANDLE hInput, hOutput;
    PFILE_OBJECT out;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attr;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK io_status_block;
    PVOID buf;
    ULONGLONG filesize;
    NTSTATUS status;

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&attr,
                             src,
                             OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
                             NULL,
                             NULL);



    status = FltCreateFile(filter,      /* Filter            */
          instance,                     /* Instance          */
          &hInput,                      /* FileHandle        */
          GENERIC_READ,                 /* DesiredAccess     */
          &attr,                        /* ObjectAttributes  */
          &io_status_block,             /* IoStatusBlock     */
          NULL,                         /* AllocationSize    */
          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,        /* FileAttributes    */
          FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,   /* ShareAccess       */
          FILE_OPEN,                    /* CreateDisposition */
          FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, /* CreateOptions     */
          NULL,                         /* EaBuffer          */
          0,                            /* EaLength          */
          IO_FORCE_ACCESS_CHECK);       /* Flags             */






    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

        DbgPrint("Could not create the file '%wZ' with STATUS '%d.\n' ",
          dest, 
          status);

      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is first time writing in C and creating a driver, I have tried reading up on IRP as I think the issue lies here. My thoughts are that the file may not exist at the time of execution, hence I get the errors - I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and show it directly here instead of linking externally.

Comment: Corrected my previous formatting edit to change `BOOL` back to he original  `BOOLEAN`

Comment: You might want to show the calling code at a minimum so those that would like to help have some idea what you've done, and can reproduce the error.  (i.e. follow the instructions in the link provided in the first comment.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but you are calling `InitializeObjectAttributes` with `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` is your `UNICODE_STRING* src` correctly cased?

Comment: Unfortunately the OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE had no impact, i have a feeling it might  be something to do with when it is executed. I have done some more testing so will add more details to the question.