# Rename file Preoperation Windows Minifilter driver

Tags: c, windows, driver

I have a minifilter driver and would like to action file renames but i am unsure how to get the new file name. I would like to run the new filename through the same criteria as Creating a file - IRP_MJ_CREATE.

I currently monitor all files within the filter and move accordingly on a set of rules.

I have found a link on SO that relates to cancelling a rename, but unsure how to get the new filename.

The link is [How to cancel a rename operation in minifilter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564824/how-to-cancel-a-rename-operation-in-minifilter-driver)

At this moment i can get the existing file name in case FileRenameInformation but i need to know what the new file name information is.

I have tried using :

```
PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION renameInfo
Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer;
```

In the switch - FileRenameInformation, but the output is always empty.

My PreOperation callback is as follows:

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PreOperationCallback(_Inout_ 
PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
_In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, 
_Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext)
{
  PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION renameInfo;
  //WCHAR buf[4096] = { 0 };

  /* IRP-based I/O operation? */
  if (FLT_IS_IRP_OPERATION(Data)) {
    /* Open file? */
    if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE) {
      /* Open file for writing/appending? */
      if (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.SecurityContext->DesiredAccess &
      (FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_APPEND_DATA)) {
    return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, DEFERRED_IO, FALSE);
  }
} else if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION) {

  switch (Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass) {

    case FileDispositionInformation:
          if (((FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION*) Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer)->DeleteFile) {
            return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, FALSE);
          }
      break;
    case FileEndOfFileInformation:
    case FileRenameInformation:

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564824/how-to-cancel-a-rename-operation-in-minifilter-driver
        renameInfo = Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer;
        //memcpy(buf, renameInfo->FileName, renameInfo->FileNameLength);
        DbgPrint("Rename info - '%wZ'", renameInfo->FileName);


      return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, TRUE);
      }
    }
  }

  return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the DbgPrint you need to use %ws

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PreOperationCallback(_Inout_ 
PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
_In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, 
_Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext)
{
  PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION renameInfo;
  //WCHAR buf[4096] = { 0 };

  /* IRP-based I/O operation? */
  if (FLT_IS_IRP_OPERATION(Data)) {
    /* Open file? */
    if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE) {
      /* Open file for writing/appending? */
      if (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.SecurityContext->DesiredAccess &
      (FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_APPEND_DATA)) {
        return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, DEFERRED_IO, 
          FALSE);
   }
 } else if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION) {

   switch (Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass) {

    case FileDispositionInformation:
          if (((FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION*) Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer)->DeleteFile) {
        return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, FALSE);
      }
  break;
    case FileEndOfFileInformation:
    case FileRenameInformation:

       DbgPrint("Original file - '%wZ'", name_info->Name);

       renameInfo = Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer;

       DbgPrint("Rename info length- '%u'", renameInfo->FileNameLength);
       DbgPrint("Rename File info - '%ws'", renameInfo->FileName);


      return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, TRUE);
    }
  }
}

return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}
```

You can call get_file_name_information to get the original file location in the code above like:

```
PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION name_info;
get_file_name_information(Data, &name_info);

//Release
FltReleaseFileNameInformation(name_info);
```

Now there is one problem the rename->FileName is in a different format to name_info->Name

The example below rename C:\temp\1.rtf to C:\temp\12.rtf

```
DbgPrint("Original file - '%wZ'", name_info->Name);
```

Will be in the format\output of:

\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Temp\1.rtf

Where as the

```
DbgPrint("Rename File info - '%ws'", renameInfo->FileName);
```

Will be in the format\output of:

\??\C:\Temp\12.rtf

```
BOOLEAN get_file_name_information(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA data,
                              PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION* name_info)
{
  /* Get name information. */
  if (NT_SUCCESS(FltGetFileNameInformation(
               data,
               FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED |
               FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_ALWAYS_ALLOW_CACHE_LOOKUP,
               name_info
             ))) {
    /* Parse file name information. */
    if (NT_SUCCESS(FltParseFileNameInformation(*name_info))) {
      return TRUE;
    }

    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(*name_info);
#if OSVER(NTDDI_VERSION) > NTDDI_WIN2K
  } else {
    /*
    * We couldn't get the "normalized" name, try to get the "opened"
    * name.
    */
    if (NT_SUCCESS(FltGetFileNameInformation(data,
                 FLT_FILE_NAME_OPENED |
                 FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_ALWAYS_ALLOW_CACHE_LOOKUP,
                 name_info
               ))) {
      if (NT_SUCCESS(FltParseFileNameInformation(*name_info))) {
        return TRUE;
      }

      FltReleaseFileNameInformation(*name_info);
    }
 #endif /* OSVER(NTDDI_VERSION) > NTDDI_WIN2K */
 }

 return FALSE;
}
```

Not sure whether this needs to be another post on Stack overflow, but if anyone knows how to change the rename->FileName to the same format/structure as name_info->Name, can they update the answer.